# What is origin of error Entity is not api accessible (Line: 1, Column: 8)

Tags: apex, error

Received error

> "Entity is not api accessible (Line: 1, Column: 8)"

Could not find what is actually causing error, or what it means.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it never contained enough detail to answer in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a line like following

```
Project p = projectsMap.get( projId );
```

When I changes this line to

```
Project__c p = projectsMap.get( projId );
```

everything has been saved ok.
Actually I meant Project__c (custom object), not sure what Project could be.

Comment: You can always edit your question to add more details to it instead of posting them as an answer. I have updated your question with your additional code. Please delete this answer post.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna This actually is an answer though, eventhough the question wasn't very clear, this explains how it was solved.

Comment: wow I m going blind.. thought these change in code is causing the above error & didn't think the other way.

Comment: Please, do not edit my question.

Comment: I ran into this confusing error when I accidentally tried to create a Queue object rather than a Group.

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this error recently when trying to use the AggregateResult class. Turns out the API version on the class in the org I was in was at 16. Moved it up to a higher API version (arbitrarily used 20.0 but could have gone to the latest, I suppose) and stopped getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some object which is used illegally. Try to rectify such errors.
Ex.

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Type__c = 'Prospect';
Direct_number__C = '';
```

Here the 3rd line should be acc.Direct_number__C = '';
See if you have made any such mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote Owner.Id instead of acc.OwnerId and got this error

Issue in my code was

```
userToRecords.put(Owner.Id,accIdAsList);
```

While it should have been

```
userToRecords.put(acc.OwnerId,accIdAsList);
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error, when I was trying to declare an instance of a Price Book standard Object.

My wrong declaration was:

PriceBook pb = new PriceBook();

Actually it should have been(after I checked with the standard dettails in Workbench):

PriceBook2 pb = new PriceBook2();

Things to keep in mind here:

- This error indicates that you are referencing to a standard object or field, in the wrong way.
- The error shows the row of the class declaration, not to the actual row where it takes place, so you have to check manually where might be the cause.

A best practice for this, is to consult with the info of the Workbench interface, that provides more dettailed info for every entity in salesforce.