# I CAN'T FIND user throwing error

Tags: user

We are getting the error below.  It’s getting thrown after a batch process but what’s confusing to me is that I can’t locate  the user that is throwing the error.  When I copy and paste the user Id I get an insufficient privileges error.  I can’t find this user Id.

Any tips on how a user Id that can’t be located is being used?

> ContactTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate
>
> caused by: System.NoAccessException: Entity is not api accessible

Comment: Hi Fred, could you add a little more context here? What code in your trigger throws this exception, and in what situation is the trigger invoked? Are you a System Administrator? Where are you seeing a User Id?

Comment: Thanks David.  The error is thrown at 1 am so we get an email with the error and the user that threw the error.   Two batch processes run at that time. That batch updates the account .  The before update uses a utility class.  The error is in the utility class at a line that sets a static variable to set an event record type.   I’m assuming the user doesn’t have access to events.  But the user associated with the error is not found.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Is it sandbox? is the Batch ran in context of some other user who get deactivated?

Comment: Do you have any code that fires platform trigger and you are subscribing to those events via trigger's process builder?

Comment: see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/69300/what-is-origin-of-error-entity-is-not-api-accessible-line-1-column-8/69301 for some ideas; this error can be a versioning error

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for responding!  This is providing the production id.  There are no code that fires trigger via process builder.. its driving me nuts why the email refers to a user that is not coming up in the prod org.  thanks again!

Comment: I’ve found What is causing the issue.  It’s s batch process triggered from a button that’s part of a managed package.  The user that shows as running the batch gives me an error (insufficient privileges) when I click on it. I’m just confused about why the user initiating the batch is not really a user.  Thanks again!!